# rotating labels

Tags: labeling

I have two questions about the following graph:

1) How can I make the x-axis labels to be just "aaa" and "bbb" and not stacked on each other?

2) How can I make the legend to be in one line? Why  LegendAppearance -> "Row" doesn't work?

```
  BarChart[{Range[4], Range[4]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"aaa", "bbb"}, 
    Below]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{"First \n Bracket", "Second \n Bracket", "Third \n Bracket",
     "Top \n Bracket"}, Below], LegendAppearance -> "Row"]
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you want. Compare BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, ChartLabels -> Placed[{"a", "b", "c"}, Top]] and BarChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}, Top]]. Is this similar to what you want ?

Comment: None of these. I want {"a","b","c"} to be shown at the bottom of the bars below the x-axis, not above the axis. And also to make them vertical.

Comment: Something like this then ? BarChart[{Range[3], Range[3]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[
    Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}, Below]}]

Comment: Thanks Lotus! I think I am getting close to what I want, just I don't know why the labels are also getting stacked when I use the stacked style: BarChart[{Range[4], Range[4]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ {"aaa", "bbb"}, 
    Below]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[{"First \n Bracket", "Second \n Bracket", "Third \n Bracket",
     "Top \n Bracket"}, Below]]

Answer (score 1):

*(This is basically a repeat of @kglr's deleted answer.)*

You can add a second argument of [`None`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/None) to the [`ChartLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartLabels) option to suppress labeling individual stacks, and you can use an explicit [`SwatchLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend) with a non-default [`LegendLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLayout) option as follows:

```
BarChart[
    {Range[4], Range[4]},
    ChartLabels->{Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree]& /@ {"aaa","bbb"},Below], None},
    ChartLayout->"Stacked",
    ChartLegends->Placed[
        SwatchLegend[
            Automatic,
            {"First \n Bracket","Second \n Bracket","Third \n Bracket","Top \n Bracket"},
            LegendLayout->{"Row",1}
        ],
        Below
    ]
]
```

[image]